# why are log4net format methods not working?

Tags: log4net, string-formatting

My application is using log4net.

When I call a logging method like this on ILog object, the logs don't always show up om the file. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. It varies by machine and by number of parameters.
    ErrorFormat("Could not send {0} to device {1} for user{2}.", data, deviceId, contact);

Yet, this always works.
    Error(string.Format("Could not send {0} to device {1} for user{2}.", data, deviceId, contact));

Why is this? Is it a glitch in log4net? Is it fixed in a later release? (currently using 1.2.10).

Comment: I don't suppose you've had any feedback?? I've currently noticed identical behaviour on our app..